# Difference between calling new and getInstance()

Tags: java, abstract-class

Is calling `Class.getInstance()` equivalent to `new Class()`?
I know the constructor is called for the latter, but what about `getInstance()`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no such method as `Class#getInstance()`. You're probably confusing it with [`Class#newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29). And yes, this does exactly the same as `new` on the *default* constructor. Here's an extract of its [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29):

> Creates a new instance of the class represented by this `Class`  object. **The class is instantiated as if by a `new`  expression with an empty argument list.** The class is initialized if it has not already been initialized.

In code,

```
Object instance = Object.class.newInstance();
```

is the same as

```
Object instance = new Object();
```

The `Class#newInstance()` call actually follows the [**Factory Method**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.

---

**Update**: seeing the other answers, I realize that there's some ambiguity in your question. Well, places where a method *actually* named `getInstance()` is been used often denotes an [**Abstract Factory**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern. It will "under the hoods" use `new` or `Class#newInstance()` to create and return the instance of interest. It's just to hide all the details about the concrete implementations which you may not need to know about.

Further you also see this methodname often in some (mostly homegrown) implementations of the [**Singleton**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern.

#### See also:

- [Real world examples of GoF design patterns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195)

Comment: Actually, he specifically said *Class.getInstance()*, so I think your first thought that he is confused is the correct one.

Comment: @Software: Yes, but he added a tag `abstract-class`. Ambiguity galore :)

Comment: `Class#newInstance()` is *not* the Factory Method Pattern. `getInstance()` methods like `Calendar.getInstance()` is however a perfect example of the Factory Method Pattern. The Abstract Factory Pattern is something different, when the factory *itself* is abstracted. `DocumentBuilderFactory` would be an example of that.

Answer (score 6):

**Absolutely (usually) not.**

`getInstance` is the static method often used with the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Java) in Java. The `new` *keyword* actually creates a new object. At some point there must be a `new` (although there are a few other methods to instantiate new objects) to actually create the object that `getInstance` returns.

Answer (score 6):

In the context of an abstract class, a `getInstance()` method may represent the [*factory method pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). An example is the abstract [`Calendar`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, which includes static factory methods and a concrete subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Some abstract classes have getInstance() methods because you can't instantiate an abstract class by using new keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is often used in Singleton Pattern. It`s used when You need only ONE instance of a class.
Using getInstance() is preferable, because implementations of this method may check is there active instance of class and return it instead of creating new one. It may save some memory. Like in this example:

```
    public static DaoMappingManager getInstance() {
    DaoProperties daoProperties = null;
    try {
        daoProperties = (DaoProperties) DaoProperties.getInstance();
    } catch (PropertyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return getInstance(daoProperties);
}

public static DaoMappingManager getInstance(DaoProperties daoProperties) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DaoMappingManager(daoProperties);
    }

    return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For start:
`newInstance()` is a `static method`. This means you can access to it without creating new class directly! And it creates that class itself "with  necessary inits" (via an inner `new myClass()`). This means you can add some `newInstance` methods (newInstance4usage1, newInstance4usage2,...) for different needs that per static method creates class with different initialization.
Sometimes, this helps class's user (final programmer) to creating class without any worry and very comfortable.

This helps really when the init process is complex or has important or or usual levels. this method don't prevent from creating class by `new` keyword.

**I like it!**

---

Excuse me for slow answering, I am typing with my mobile phone!